# Steam error: ''You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1''

Tags: steam

Yeah like i said in the title it brings up the terminal that is installing the plugin then it fails to download them. Then it closes. Next it brings up

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
>   libGL.so.1

Finally I close that and steam box opens up and says

> Steam-fatal error'' Fatal error:failed to load Steamui.so''.

That's basically my problem.

Comment: What is Ubuntu version?

Comment: The same problem occurred on my 20.04 LTS version when I installed *.deb package directly from steampowered.com. Dylan Cali's answer is good solution.

Answer (score 5):

For me this was solved by:

1. Creating `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf` with the contents:

   ```
   /usr/lib32
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
   ```
2. Running `sudo ldconfig` to update the shared library cache
3. installing/reinstalling the 32bit mesa libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
   ```

[Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: fair enough, I've updated my answer to break down the steps explicitly, and simply linked to the original forum post as my source

Comment: Oh wow, this helped me while literally NOTHING else did. I had the same error message, but my problem was the need to actually reinstall the libgl1 library with all the dependencies. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall steam and then run `sudo apt-get install steam`.

It seems that Valve didn't package steam that well but luckily you can install it with apt just fine.